# Can I put a complete namespace in a specific section?

Tags: c++, gcc, avr-gcc

I am working on an embedded project and have to put a complete section of our code in a specific memory region. We are using avr-gcc.
The normal way to go is to tell GCC to put the function in a section with:

```
__attribute__((__section__(".text_sdram"))) void foo(void);
```

However, this would cost us a lot of effort plus the chance to "forget" one function.
We are using C++ and all the function that have to be in .text_sdram is put in a specific namespace. 
Is it possible to put a complete namespace in a specific section?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Pieter

Comment: This sounds like a case for a test case script which checks the link time assertion that all symbols from that namespace are in the correct section. Then, if you "forget" one function, the build will fail. Whether you implement that with a linker script, an awk script going through a map file, a python script with pybfd, or something completely different is your decision. Yes, there are runtime and compile time assertions in relatively recent incarnations of the C and C++ languages, but for link time assertions you are still on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) the visibility attribute can be attached to a namespace, but it doesn't look like anything else can.  You could try attaching the section attribute to your namespace using the same syntax as described for visibility.  I don't expect it to work, and if it doesn't I'm fairly sure there's not a good answer.  If your namespace is all defined in a single module, or can be rearranged that way, you can probably solve this with a linker script.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for your reply. The section attribute does not work. It  is possible to use the linker script, for this, I need to put all the object files in a specific section.